# Can we cancel differentials in partial derivatives? $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial \dot{x}}?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm not sure whether this is better suited to the physics site, but I'm trying here first.

My analytical mechanics professor, while discussing some generalized coordinate $q(x(t),y(t))$, used the following identity:$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial \dot{x}}$$

and I couldn't understand why/whether it is true? My assumption was that we could construct a proof along these lines:

> By the chain rule: $$\dot{q}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$ So taking the derivative by $\dot{x}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ we get: $$\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{x}}(\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}\dot{x})+\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{x}}(\frac{\partial q}{\partial y}\dot{y})=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+0=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$$

But I can't convince myself that I can take the partial derivative with respect to $\dot{x}$ in this way.

I tried to apply this identity to an example but this only confused me further: 
$$q(x(t))=x^2, x(t)=t^2\quad$$$$ \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=2x=2t^2\quad \dot{x}=2t, \dot{q}=4t^3=\frac{\dot{x}^3}{2}\quad $$$$\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{3\dot{x}^2}{2}=6t^2\not=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$$

Comment: You have to be  careful that these are partial derivatives. In your example, you expressed $x$ with $\dot{x}$, and that changes the meaning. For partial derivative, $2x \dot{x}$ and $\dot{x}^3/2$ are not the same. About the question: it works, but only if $q$ does not depend on $\dot{x}$, too. For example, $q=x^2+\dot{x}^2$ would violate the equality.

Comment: @orion Could you elaborate on why independence on $\dot{x}$ is sufficient? Is there a name to this 'theorem'?

Comment: You have all you need in yellow frame. If $q(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$, then you will get additional terms, because then, $\partial q/\partial\dot{x}$ and even $\partial q/\partial x$ could still depend on $\dot{q}$. Consider again $x^2+\dot{x}^2$. You get $\partial q/\partial x=2x$, but $\dot{q}=2x\dot{x}+2\dot{x}\ddot{x}$, so $\partial \dot{q}/\partial\dot{x}=2x+2\ddot{x}$.